# Use .htaccess to show different users different pages (via redirect or otherwise)

Tags: .htaccess, http, authentication, redirect, web

I am trying to create an event website with very rudimentary authentication and to show different content to different users.  Two types of users: guests and specialguests.  I'm trying to figure out if it is possible to have a page such as http://mysite.com/RSVP redirect to one of two locations based on the user who is authenticated - either [mydomain]/RSVP/form1.html for "guest" or [mydomain]/RSVP/form2.html for "specialguest"

Is it possible to have a conditional redirect like this?

Comment: It depends on the authentication method but I don't see any reason to use .htaccess instead of doing the redirect in the application itself